# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.phtml in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

**The code for index.phtml as follows:**

```
<?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry): ?>
    <?php echo $this->escape($entry->email) ?>
    <br></br>
    <?php echo $this->escape($entry->comment) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**The code for indexAction() in IndexController:**

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $guestbook = new Application_Model_HRModel();
    $view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' =>'C:/Users/398853/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject3/application/views/scripts/index'));
    $view->entries = $guestbook->fetchAll();
    echo $view->render('index.phtml');

}
```

**The code for fetchAll() in Application_Model_HRModel:**

```
    public function fetchAll() 
   {
       $entry = new Application_Model_HRMo();
       $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();
       $entries   = array();
       foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
        $entry->setId($row->id);
        $entry->setEmail($row->email);       
        $entry->setCreated($row->created);
        $entry->setComment($row->comment);
        $entries[] = $entry;
    }

            return $entries;
```

}
I have 3 entries i.e. 3 rows in my databse table .
But When i request the url as http://localhost:8888/Index  it says 
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\39885Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\application\views\scripts\index\index.phtml on line 54 and then display last row's entry 3 times.I think problem occurs because at first it executes index.phtml and without executing indexAction()(which further executes fetchAll()) $entries will not an array Thats Why at first it gives above stated warning. Now tell me how to start execution from indexAction() then come at index.phtml so that $entries would be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `fetchAll()` you use the same object, but you should create new in loop. That's why you have 3 duplicated rows in output. About PHP warning - tru to `var_dump($this->entries)` and check the type

Comment: Now I have got 3 different rows.when i use var_dump, null is returned because initially its nothing because indexAction() has not called So the thing is how to begin execution from indexAction() instead of index.phtml so that index.phtml gets the $entries updated one i.e. an array.Thanks for Reply.

Comment: `index.phtml` is executed from `echo $view->render('index.phtml');`. May be you called it from somewhere else? You can print backtrace (`debug_print_backtrace`) if you don't know where is the first invocation.

Comment: When I used debug_print_backtrace in init() in IndexController the result was as follows:#0 IndexController->init() #1 Zend_Controller_Action->__construct ............ #2 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch #3 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() called at \Bootstrap.php:97 #4 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() called at \Application.php:366] #5 Zend_Application->run() called at public\index.php:26] Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.phtml on line 55 and then the data from table gets printed Now what should be done Plz Suggest

Comment: You should put debug_print_backtrace into your view (phtml)

Comment: when i use var_dump($this->entries) it displays null first followed by above stated warning and then displays the array containing values from database table.But Why it is displaying null initially and after that it displays warning and then the correct array??